# Fault module: kernelbase.dll . Application crash

Tags: .net

I Have an `application` done in .`Net framework 3.5` (C#.Net).
I installed the application in `Windows 7`. But while opening some forms, the application causes the following error 
[image]

If anybody knows the solution please share. This error comes only in windows 7.

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose the problem. Try connecting a debugger.

Comment: The exception code indicates it crashed on a soft stackoverflow.  That's a bug in your code, you'll need to fix it.  Use a debugger to find out where that bug is located.

Comment: Hans found that information by simply doing a Web search for `e053534f`. You could've done that yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add because I got the same issue:

Sometimes this is related to a stack overflow due to recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem and found a solution.

Check your event viewer and find out what application caused the crash. It is probably kernelbase.dll. This is not an office problem as KERNELBASE.dll is a system file. In case a system file causes the crash, then you need to fix your windows 7 system files.

Go here and follow all instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Doing this solved many other problems I had with my system:

- MSN messenger not loading any more
- All office 2010 programs crashing whenever I tried to click on the INSERT tab
- windows explorer crashing when searching for files or documents in large folders

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that the Windows Service setup project or part of the solution had become corrupt; it was not detecting dependencies correctly and so caused an IO problem when trying to start the Windows Service.

So I basically deleted the old setup project and recreated a new one, then when I added the Primary Output it still did not update dependencies correctly, If I then added another Primary Output the dependencies would populate, then if I tried to delete one of the now two Primary Output entries VS2010 would crash, so I viewed the files of the setup project, then added three, then deleted two entries?!?!?!?! et voila ... no more crashing.

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was using Dependency Injection + an Installer. The installer merged the contents of multiple application folders and therefore i had assembly version mismatches which resulted in loading issues.

The solution was consolidating the referenced assemblies for me.