# Winforms app crashes on Windows server 2008r2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms application that connects to X_Trader via ttapi.
(Info about X_Trader [here](https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/platforms/x_trader-platform/))
The application runs fine on windows7 machines but on server it crashes as soon as it startsup.
From the crash report I found that KernelBase.dll is causing this.
I have put logs on everyline to see for which line the application is crashing.
From the logs, I found that it crashes while creating a instance of UIDispatcher of TT( Dispatcher disp = Dispatcher.AttachUIDispatcher()).
I am gonna paste the error details from crash report.

> Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
>     Application Name: TradingSystemsLiveFeed.exe
>     Application Version:  1.0.0.0
>     Application Timestamp:    57106fc3
>     Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.23250
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   562593c7
>     Exception Code:   e0434352
>     Exception Offset: 000000000000adcd
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.400.8
>     Locale ID:    2057
>     Additional Information 1: 367e
>     Additional Information 2: 367e805d0e7c1ec3f63b05bb5ce5c416
>     Additional Information 3: 2279
>     Additional Information 4: 2279f56534e3e1288468aa2f740c7a91
>   Read our privacy statement online:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>   If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>     C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: Might be the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327908/fault-module-kernelbase-dll-application-crash.
the error log doesnt give much to go on, you could check the .net version on the server

Comment: From programs and features I am able to see that dotnet framework 4.5 is installed but from add/remove components  I am able to see only 3.5.

Comment: _Might_ be something related to that. Are your application running .NET 4.5? You could try to reinstall, not sure it will make any difference but could be worth trying

Comment: Add proper logging to your application and write any exceptions to a log file. It's impossible to guess what's wrong from a generic error message. You can also try remote debugging, although that can't be used in production. You *do* need to add logging.

Comment: With the help of log files I was able to understand that the error was due to this line **(Dispatcher disp = Dispatcher.AttachUIDispatcher())**

Comment: @Henningsson I installed 4.6 and tried, the error is same..