# .NET 4.0 Application Stopped working

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am running a Deployed Winform application developed in .NET 4.0 & SQL Server Compact Edition Database File. While opening the crystal report (CRforVS_13_0_9),  Application Stopped working . My EventLog shows

> Description:
>   
> Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:
>   
> Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
>   
> Application Name:  Hospital System Lite.exe
>   
> Application Version:   1.1.0.0
>   
> Application Timestamp: 585adbab
>   
> Fault Module Name: KERNELBASE.dll
>   
> Fault Module Version:  6.1.7601.17514
>   
> Fault Module Timestamp:    4ce7b8f0
>   
> Exception Code:    e0434352
>   
> Exception Offset:  0000b760
>   
> OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>   
> Locale ID: 1033
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>   
> C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

What I have tried is:

1. Run as Administrator
2. Run another user profile
3. Create new user Change connection

Comment: http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2009/07/finding-clr-exceptions-with-visual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by Gilles:

Check your event viewer and find out what application caused the crash. It is probably kernelbase.dll. This is not an office problem as KERNELBASE.dll is a system file. In case a system file causes the crash, then you need to fix your windows 7 system files.

Go here and follow all instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Doing this solved many other problems I had with my system:

```
MSN messenger not loading any more
All office 2010 programs crashing whenever I tried to click on the INSERT tab
windows explorer crashing when searching for files or documents in large folders
```

Hope this helps.

[Fault module: kernelbase.dll . Application crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327908/fault-module-kernelbase-dll-application-crash)